# Python 2.80: Apply modifiers to curve

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers

I am trying to apply the whole stack of modifiers on an object in Blender 2.80

The object might be a curve, in which case I sometimes get the error:

"RuntimeError: Error: Transform curve to mesh in order to apply constructive modifiers"

So I guess I need to convert it to mesh, but if I do to_mesh() then I only get a mesh that is disconnected from the scene, right? How do I replace the objects data with the newly created mesh so I can apply the modifiers on it?

Also, can I be sure all modifier types will work on such a mesh?

Comment: Using bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')?

Comment: @lemon Thats a 2.79 method, right? The 2.80 API reference does not list it:
 https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.Object.html

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.convert

Comment: @lemon thanks. Will all types of modifiers work on a mesh, do you know?

Comment: The modifiers will be applied during the conversion. Don't think there is an exception to that (except maybe linked objects alt+d), but give it a try.